# Is there an autocorrect for windows?

Tags: windows, autocomplete, spell-check, autocorrect

Is there a way to get the auto-correct feature (found in almost all mobile devices) in windows?

[image: a mobile device's auto-correct feature suggesting correct spelling of a misspelt word]

I know spell-check, but you still have to manually right-click and choose, and it also doesn't work in many text-boxes like the address bar.

Comment: Related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/autocorrect-anywhere-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the Word Expander software is one way to get that in Windows 7 or earlier.

Microsoft Word, Internet Explorer 10 and later, Windows 8, and Windows Phone 8 are some of the programs and systems that each have an autocorrect feature of their own.